# ddply with user defined functions

Tags: r, plyr, reshape2

I am wondering how to use ddply to call multiple user defined functions. Current Solution:

```
require(plyr)
data(mtcars)
#MY UDF
carTest<-function(cars){
    dratCut= max(cars$drat)
    mpgCut = max(cars$mpg)
    best = subset(cars, cars$drat< dratCut & cars$mpg < mpgCut)
    return (best$hp) 
 }

 x= ddply(mtcars, .(cyl,gear), function(mtcars.sub) mean(carTest(mtcars.sub)))
 y = ddply(mtcars, .(cyl,gear), function(mtcars.sub) sd(carTest(mtcars.sub)))
 final = cbind(x, y$V1)
```

I want ddply to split my dataframe  into multiple dataframes, call the UDF on the split, and compute statistics on the return value.
My current solution accomplishes this by calling ddply (and carTest) twice.

Is there a better way? I've simplified the UDF to make the code simpler, so factoring out the UDF is not ideal.

Comment: From the `final`, it looks like you wanted a single dataset?  If that is the case `summarise_each` from `dplyr` would be easier or even `aggregate` from `base R`.  Please do provide some example dataset.

Comment: switched to mtcars(). Trying to modify your solutions, but my rStudio doesn't like %>%.

Comment: I assume that you don't have package dplyr installed.

Comment: Right. Somehow `require(dplyr)` still worked.
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
late %>%
      group_by(elapsed, CreditGrade)%>%
      summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE),
                         sd=sd(., na.rm=TRUE) , median=median(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Using the `mtcars` dataset

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$wt[c(3,5)] <- NA
mtcars %>% 
     group_by(gear) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE),
                     sd=sd(., na.rm=TRUE)), wt, qsec)
#   gear  wt_mean qsec_mean     wt_sd  qsec_sd
#1    3 3.924929    17.692 0.8546165 1.349916
#2    4 2.643636    18.965 0.6562739 1.613880
#3    5 2.632600    15.640 0.8189254 1.130487
```

Or using `aggregate`

```
do.call(`data.frame`,aggregate(cbind(wt,qsec)~gear,mtcars,
        FUN=function(x) c(mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
                       sd=sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)), na.action=NULL))
#  gear  wt.mean     wt.sd qsec.mean  qsec.sd
#1    3 3.924929 0.8546165    17.692 1.349916
#2    4 2.643636 0.6562739    18.965 1.613880
#3    5 2.632600 0.8189254    15.640 1.130487
```

#### Update

Regarding using the `multiple` user defined functions inside `ddply`, instead of calling `ddply` twice, you can use `c` or `cbind` inside the first call

```
 res <- ddply(mtcars, .(cyl,gear), function(mtcars.sub) 
               c(mean(carTest(mtcars.sub)), sd(carTest(mtcars.sub))))

 res
 #  cyl gear        V1       V2
 #1   4    3       NaN       NA
 #2   4    4  81.83333 19.65112
 #3   4    5       NaN       NA
 #4   6    3 105.00000       NA
 #5   6    4       NaN       NA
 #6   6    5       NaN       NA
 #7   8    3 191.00000 31.95483
 #8   8    5 335.00000       NA
```

Comment: @SamShleifer - if you have `dplyr` loaded, enter `?\`%>%\`` in the console

Comment: Thanks, only had plyr loaded.

Comment: This works for the mtcars example, because you want it to run mean() on the specified columns, but doesn't work for my example, because I want it to run carTest on the WHOLE data frame, and spit out one value. I don't want to call carTest() for each row. I want to call it once for each group of columns.

Comment: I want to call `carTest` on the whole data frame, not specific columns.

Comment: Is there a `dplyr` only solution?

Comment: @SamShleifer  You may have to change the function according to `dplyr`.  The possible solution is `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% filter(drat < max(drat) & mpg <max(mpg)) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sd), hp)`